# Flatten inner matrices

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the following two nested lists

```
atest = {{{{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}}, {{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}}}, {{{c1, 
      c2}, {c3, c4}}, {{d1, d2}, {d3, d4}}}};
atest // MatrixForm
btest = {{a1, a2, b1, b2}, {a3, a4, b3, b4}, {c1, c2, d1, d2}, {c3, 
    c4, d3, d4}};
btest // MatrixForm
```

how can I use Mathematica / WL commands to turn `atest` into `btest`? i.e. to remove the inner matrices.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your original question asked for use of `Flatten` and `Transpose`, but you accepted an [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) answer. That is why I edited your question.

Comment: Voting to close as "described in the documentation", but it is very likely that this question is a duplicate to an older one at MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
atest = {{{{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}}, {{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}}}, {{{c1, 
      c2}, {c3, c4}}, {{d1, d2}, {d3, d4}}}};
ArrayFlatten[atest]
```

Here is a link to [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html).

Comment: (+1) Did not see your answer, before posting mine. But OP requested to use `Transpose` and `Flatten`. (OP might prefer those operations for some reason...)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest method I could come up with:

```
b = Join @@ Join[
  atest[[All, 1]],
  atest[[All, 2]],
  3
];
b === btest
```

> True

or:

```
b = Join @@ Join[Sequence @@ Transpose[atest], 3]
b === btest
```

> True